# Memory Leak with CComPtr

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, visual-leak-detector

I using crtdbg to detect leak position and I got memory leak when calling `new`

```
CComPtr<IDBColumnInfo> m_spColumnInfo
CComPtr<CDBColumnInfo> spResult = new CDBColumnInfo(); //Memory leak here
//another logic come here to set data to spResult
//another logic come here to set data to spResult
//another logic come here to set data to spResult
m_spColumnInfo = static_cast<IDBColumnInfo*>(spResult.Detach());
spResult.Release();
```

Are there any step need to do with spResult?

Comment: Why do you need `spResult.Detach()`?  Why not do: `m_spColumnInfo = static_cast<CDBColumnInfo*>(spResult)`?    I haven't used `CComPtr` in a while, but the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/reference/ccomptr-class?view=vs-2019#operator_eq) says that `operator=` increments the reference count, so by using `Detach`, I think you're going to end up with an extra `AddRef` without a corresponding `Release` when you try to transfer ownership.

Comment: There's isn't any more detail.  Try replacing the line with `spResult.Detach()` with the line I suggested.

Comment: @jamesdlin I got exception in this function https://pastebin.com/LkWT2bhU

Comment: After looking at your actual code: you shouldn't need `delete spResult` at all either.  Also, I would declare `spResult` as `CComPtr<IDBColumnInfo>` and then get rid of the `static_cast` entirely.

Comment: @jamesdlin I change to `CComPtr<IDBColumnInfo> spResult = new CDBColumnInfo();` but have some function of `CDBColumnInfo` could not access by `spResult `. Ex `HRESULT CDBColumnInfo::GetField (LPCOLESTR fieldName  )`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192748/discussion-between-jamesdlin-and-ryo).

Comment: What is `m_spColumnInfo` declared as? Is it a raw `IDBColumnInfo*` pointer, or another `CComPtr`? `Detach()` does not decrement the refcount, so make sure the assignment of `m_spColumnInfo` does not increment it or you will create a leak. And make sure that `m_spColumnInfo` is eventually `Release`'d after the detach. And FYI, calling `spResult.Release()` after `spResult.Detach()` is a no-op. Any time you manually `Release()`/`Detach()` a smart pointer like `CComPtr`, you better know what you are doing. Question yourself why you need to do it at all.

Comment: @RemyLebeau `CComPtr<IDBColumnInfo> m_spColumnInfo;` => this is declaration. As a newbie in C++, I try to using `Release()` to clear memory and you point out that is no-op. I learned with thanks ;).

Answer (score 1):

You have a memory leak, because you are mismanaging the `CDBColumnInfo` object's reference count.

When you initialize `spResult`, the object's refcount is initialized to 1. When you call `spResult.Detach()`, the object still has a refcount of 1, as `Detach()` does not decrement it.  When the detached pointer is then assigned to `m_spColumnInfo`, the object's refcount is incremented to 2.  When `m_spColumnInfo` is released later on, it decrements the object's recount to 1, and the object is leaked.

You should not be detaching `spResult` at all. Assign it as-is to `m_spColumnInfo`, which will increment the refcount to 2, and then let `spResult` go out of scope normally, decrementing the refcount to 1, leaving `m_spColumnInfo` with the only active reference.  When `m_spColumnInfo` is then released later on, the refcount will be decremented to 0, and the object will be freed.

You shouldn't be trying to manage the refcount manually at all. That defeats the whole purpose of using `CComPtr`.

```
CComPtr<IDBColumnInfo> m_spColumnInfo;

...

{
    CComPtr<CDBColumnInfo> spResult = new CDBColumnInfo();
    //set data to spResult
    m_spColumnInfo = spResult;
}
```

Also, on a side note, your function has no business calling `CoInitialize()` and `CoUninitialize()` at all! You need to remove those calls from your function (especially since your function does not even call `CoUninitialize()` in most of the code paths that exit your function). Those calls are not your function's responsibility to make. It is the responsibility of the thread that calls your function to decide how it needs to initialize COM for itself. Those COM functions should be called only once per thread, not per user function.